# Find the turning point of the plot

Tags: plotting

[image: zero point and turning point]

This is a simple plot.

```
Plot[Abs[1 + x] - Abs[-3 + 2 x], {x, -8, 8}]
```

I want to ask whether *Mathematica* has some command that can directly get the zero point or turning point from the plot.

In an interactive manner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the maximum...

```
FindMaximum[Abs[1 + x] - Abs[-3 + 2 x], x]
{2.5, {x -> 1.5}}
```

For the zeroes:

```
Solve[Abs[1 + x] - Abs[-3 + 2 x] == 0, x]
{{x -> 2/3}, {x -> 4}}
```

For the "turning points" look for places where the derivative (slope) from the left is not equal to the derivative (slope) from the right:

```
f[x_] := Abs[1 + x] - Abs[-3 + 2 x];
g[x_] := D[f[x], x]; 
all = Table[{p, Limit[g[x], x -> p, Direction -> 1] == 
         Limit[g[x], x -> p, Direction -> -1] // FullSimplify}, {p, -2, 5, 0.1}];
Select[all, #[[2]] == False &]

{{-1., False}, {1.5, False}}
```

So the turning points are at -1 and 1.5.

Comment: In an interactive manner, can do this?   turning point

Comment: What is the "turning point"?

Comment: Please look at the plot, there are two zero point and two turning point.

Comment: I thought a turning point was an x-value where a local maximum or local minimum happens.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork "Turning point" is, as in bill's answer, [a point at which the derivative changes sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turning_Point). I know it from time series analysis, e.g. from Kendall & Stuart "The Advanced Theory of Statistics", or Brockwell & Davis "Time Series: Theory and Methods". It's a valid term.

Comment: @corey979:  So given your definition, the comment from the poser himself—"there are two zero point and *two turning point*"—would be incorrect.  Right?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork According to what I encountered, and according to "derivative changes sign", a _turning point_ is a local extremum, so yes, in the OP's plot there's one turning point. I guess the OP meant it like bill s understood it, but I wouldn't call it valid - maybe there's also another context that I'm not aware of, though.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork @corey979 - Perhaps "break" is a better term than "turning point". Another approach for this function: `breaks = Cases[f[x], Abs[z_] :> (Solve[z == 0, x, Reals][[1]]), Infinity]`

Answer (score 3):

For this particular example [`PiecewiseExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PiecewiseExpand.html) can be useful. Depending on what you mean by turning point, you can use the complement of the function domain of the derivative:

```
fun[x_] := Abs[1 + x] - Abs[-3 + 2 x]
g[x_] := PiecewiseExpand[fun[x], Reals]
pts = {x, 
    fun[x]} /. {ToRules@Reduce[Not[FunctionDomain[D[g[x], x], x]], x]};
Plot[fun[x], {x, -8, 8}, Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[pts]}]
```

[image]